# Programmatically determine NUMA node or PCI bus, device, function number of Direct3D9Ex device

Tags: windows, direct3d, numa

I'm looking for a way to programmatically determine which NUMA node a particular Direct3D9Ex display adapter is connected to so that I can allocate memory for host to device transfers on that node.

I can use IDirect3D9Ex::GetAdapterIdentifier() to obtain a DeviceName of the form "\.\DISPLAY1".

I can use EnumDisplayDevices() to enumerate the display devices and match this DeviceName to a DeviceKey of the form "\Registry\Machine\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Video{62E184AC-2614-4AA8-844C-47454B92C142}\0000".

I can use SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo() to enumerate devices and SetupDiGetDeviceProperty() to query properties including DEVPKEY_NAME (e.g. "NVIDIA GeForce GTX TITAN X"), DEVPKEY_Device_LocationInfo (e.g. "PCI bus 2, device 0, function 0") and DEVPKEY_Device_Numa_Node (e.g. 0) but I can't find anything to link one of these devices to either the DeviceName or DeviceKey in EnumDisplayDevices().

I can do equivalent thing is CUDA because cudaDeviceGetPCIBusId() provides the PCI bus, device and function information but I also need to do it in Direct3D9Ex (when CUDA is unavailable).

The other thing I've noticed is that in the registry under "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_17C2&SUBSYS_113210DE&REV_A1" there is a key for each of my display devices and each one contains another key called "Device Parameters" with a value called "VideoID" of the form "{62E184AC-2614-4AA8-844C-47454B92C142}". Unfortunately applications are not supposed to read this part of the registry directly and I don't know how to obtain the same information through the SETUPAPI.

Comment: Why are you using legacy Direct3D9Ex (Windows Vista era) instead of DirectX 11?

Comment: It's a legacy code path to support old and non-NVIDIA hardware. The primary code path uses CUDA. Maybe it could still be updated to DirectX 11 though. Would that help though?