# Programmatically determine NUMA node or PCI bus, device, function number of generic PCI device

Tags: linux, kernel, pci, numa

I pretty much need the same thing as [Programmatically determine NUMA node or PCI bus, device, function number of Direct3D9Ex device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45793586/programmatically-determine-numa-node-or-pci-bus-device-function-number-of-dire)

I'm looking for a way to programmatically determine which NUMA node a particular PCI device is connected to so that I can allocate memory for host to device transfers on that node.

So, my code opens a device file like `/dev/mydev0`, `/dev/mydev1`, etc. I can have several of those device files, and they can be on different NUMA nodes. What I need to figure out is the NUMA node, if any, that device belongs to, in **application code**.

I'm writing the device driver for these devices. I understand that the pointer for a [`struct device`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/driver-api/infrastructure.html?highlight=device_create#c.device) returned by [`device_create`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/driver-api/infrastructure.html?highlight=device_create#c.device_create) has the field

```
#ifdef CONFIG_NUMA;
  int numa_node;
#endif;
```

My idea would be to export that value through a custom ioctl call in my custom driver.

What I'm asking is if there's a more standard way to do map the `/dev` entry to a NUMA node so an **application** can figure that out and use something like [`numa_bind`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/numa) so the memory allocations happens on the correct node.

I also understand that I can check the NUMA node of a PCI device with `lspci`. I don't see how can I use that based on the `/dev` entry.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Sysfs` to the rescue! Say that your device is `/dev/fb0`, then

```
$ cat  /sys/class/graphics/fb0/device/numa_node
0
```

Will give you the NUMA node.

Opening `/sys/class/graphics/fb0/device/numa_node` in text mode and reading from it will yield `"0\n"` (`0x30`, `0x0A`).